# How to mute and unmute chats in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function:

```
function change_mute_status_callback(data, inputs){
    show_spinner("#chat-list-option-mute", "revert")
    if(data.status != 'success') return
    if(data.is_mute){
        $("#chat-list-option-mute").attr("src","images/chat/o-mute.svg")
        $("#id-"+inputs.chat_id).attr("is-mute","1")
    }
    else{
        $("#chat-list-option-mute").attr("src","images/chat/o-unmute.svg")
        $("#id-"+inputs.chat_id).attr("is-mute","0")
    }
}
```

I want to mute and unmute chat and when I click on the mute icon I want to change the image icon, but it changes the first time and then does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions???

Comment: Really no one can help me????!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: no one is hear!!!!!!!!??????????

Comment: please i do not have time!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change it to:

```
function change_mute_status_callback(data, inputs){
    show_spinner("#chat-list-option-mute", "revert")
    if(data.status != 'success') return
    if(data.is_mute === '0'){// change here
        $("#chat-list-option-mute").attr("src","images/chat/o-mute.svg")
        $("#id-"+inputs.chat_id).attr("is-mute","1")
    }
    else{
        $("#chat-list-option-mute").attr("src","images/chat/o-unmute.svg")
        $("#id-"+inputs.chat_id).attr("is-mute","0")
    }
}
```

when ur getting the attr is_mute it will return string so it will allways be true.

Comment: i do it but nothing changed @Talg123

Comment: for understanding that is mute or unmute

Comment: yes but how do u get that data.is_mute??
where do u get it from? kinda need to see the full code.(html)

Comment: see when i click on image the spinner worked but the image do nat change and it also it work just for the first time